# How can I list all the nodes in my database?

Tags: python-3.x, django-2.0

I'm trying to create a simple model `Node` and a simple web page that shows all of my nodes in a list. But it seems not working and everytime I change the code I got a new error. So I gave up and came to here.This is what I did:
I created a Node model:

```
class Node(models.Model):
    ID = models.DecimalField(max_digits=9, decimal_places=6)
    nb_solenoid = models.DecimalField(max_digits=9, decimal_places=6, null=True, blank=True)
    connexion = models.CharField(max_length=255)

    def get_absolute_url(self):
        return reverse("node:index", kwargs={"id": self.id})
```

with this form:

```
class NodeForm(forms.ModelForm):
ID = forms.DecimalField(initial=0)
nb_solenoid = forms.DecimalField(initial=1)
connexion = forms.CharField(required=False,
                            widget=forms.Textarea(
                                  attrs={
                                      "placeholder": "type of connexion"
                                  }))
    class Meta:
        model = Node
        fields = [
            'ID',
            'nb_solenoid',
            'connexion'
        ]
```

And this is my views.py:

```
def index(request):
    queryset = Node.objects.all()
    context = {
        "object_list": queryset
    }
    return render(request, "node/index.html", context)
```

This is my code in urls.py:

```
urlpatterns = [path('', views.index, name='index')]
```

When I call this url: `http://localhost:8000/node` I get this error now:

```
NoReverseMatch at /node
Reverse for 'index' with keyword arguments '{'id': 1}' not found. 1 pattern(s) tried: ['node$']
```

What is a NoReverseMatch error and how do I fix my problem? Let me say that I'm a Django beginner developer.
Thank you.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The issue is that your named url path `node:index` takes no arguments (presumably because that view is just listing out all the nodes, not a specific node), yet your model's `get_absolute_url` is trying to reverse the pattern with a kwarg of `id`. The core problem is your `get_absolute_url` method; however, you really probably also would benefit from just using class based generic views:

urls.py:

```
urlpatterns = [
  path('nodes/', NodeList.as_view(), name="node-list"),
  path('node/<id>/', NodeDetail.as_view(), name="node-detail")
]
```

view.py:

```
from django.views.generic import ListView, DetailView

from .models import Node


class NodeList(ListView):
   model = Node


class NodeDetail(DetailView):
   model = Node
```

models.py:

```
class Node(models.Model):
  <snip>
    def get_absolute_url(self):
        return reverse("node-detail", kwargs={"id": self.id})
```

I really should have mentioned, documentation for class based generic views are at: https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/2.1/topics/class-based-views/generic-display/